# Why do my MIPS crosscompiler works like this for NOT operation?

Tags: mips, xor, nor

I setup my crosscompiler for making MIPS instructions.

And it compiles C code well.

but I found a weird thing for NOT operations.

if i make code like

```
   int a;
   func(!a);
```

and i studied MIPS instructions with text book that says 
"MIPS converts NOT operation to 'nor with zero'"

So i thought it would converted like

```
 nor a a $zero
```

but my compiler converts

```
xori a a 0x0
sltu a 1
```

///////////////////////////////////////
i compiled the code with 'myaccount>> mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -S myfilename.c'
and it makes myfilename.s file..

what am i missing??

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "not" operations. The "nor with 0" operation is `~a` (1's complement), while you wrote `!a` (which returns 1 if the operand is 0 or 0 otherwise).